# Bootstrap Datepicker - Months and Years have no spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am working with the Bootstrap Date picker from http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/ and on the example they are showing it formats and shows nicely with spacing between the months and the years in a grid style.

However using their js and css files the months and the years are all showing together please see the images below as a reference.

[image]

are there any options or things that I am missing in order for this to show correctly.

thanks

Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you don't have javascript errors in your console. Maybe there's something else in your script that breaks the datepicker.
If you don't have errors, make sure both boostrap's JS and CSS file are correctly loaded.

Comment: Simon, can you please indicate how this was solved. I have the same issue. No errors in the console. What do you mean with "bad ordering"?

Comment: @Davy Check if your file are loaded in the correct order. Refer to the documentation [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to make sure you have all the files in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in 2021 with Bootstrap 5 and Datapicker version 1.9

I added this style directive in a CSS or the page itself, as years and decades are within a span, embedded in a table row  that is itself within a div (not really "boostrap minded", but the datepicker is probably now much older than the core Boostrap framework ...).

```
<style>
    div.datepicker-years span{
         margin-left: 5px; 
         margin-right: 5px; 
    }
</style>
```

Adapt the directive at your convenience (this example is just for the year screen) .

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script on the page, assuming that your input fild has the name `dob` and use `id="date" type="text"`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var date_input=$('input[name="dob"]'); 
    var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    date_input.datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
    })
})
```